# Json object from BeanShellPreprocessor is not replaced in HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter, load, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

This is the Hierarchy i have on my Testplan
[image]

I have Beanshell preprocessor as below:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("customerId", "1234");
obj.put("dataSourceName", "ABCD");
JSONArray relateddata = new JSONArray();
relateddata.add("abc", "abc");
obj.put("relatedData", relateddata);

String data = obj.toJSONString();

vars.put("request", data);
```

My HttP Request is as below:

```
${request};
```

My RequestBody is :

```
POST http://www.url.com (just an example)

POST data:
${request};

[no cookies]
```

Could someone help me understand why my request variable is not being replaced and how can i get that replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonArray cannot be added to Jsonobject directly without converting into to JSONobject.

Answer (score 0):

You should put request as a string

```
  vars.put("request", data);
```

Comment: It was a typp, fixed it.